# How do I send fake request data to a RSpec/Capybara request/integration spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, request, capybara

I want to create a request spec to test the full experience after a user signs up via Facebook Connect. Depending on the sign up results (i.e., successfully signed up vs. errors during sign up), the experience will differ. What I want to be able to do is send/pass fake request data for these different cases to my controller that handles the Facebook OAuth response.

I was hoping to be able to do something likes:

```
visit facebook_handler_path, :request_data => fake_fb_data_hash
```